# Why is the_content() (and get_the_content()) unstyled in my WordPress page?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm absolutely new to WordPress theming but I decided to learn on the job and I really want the site to go live within the next week or so. I've stuck to a simple index.php (no templates or template-parts). I'm able to receive the contents in the proper format which they were published (with inline images, line breaks, etc.) but the css styling is absent. What could I be doing wrong?

```
<article <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <div class="entry-content">
         <?php 
                
              $content = wpautop(get_the_content());
              echo $content;
          ?>
    </div>   
</article>
```

I realize there is a difference between the singular view and the list view (the loop). The list view doesn't actually style the content by default. Could that be where my problem lies, and if so, what's the best way to get around this problem?

EDIT
Essentially, I want the singular view (singular.php) within the index.php.  When you visit the site you're greeted by an entire article, not previews and listings. So I don't actually need the loop for now. I simply retrieve the post and display the contents on the index page.

**That is literally the only thing keeping my site from going online right now. I just need that article to be styled as it's supposed to be. There are only two files in my theme: index.php and style.css. I've already tried the_content(), I've also tried apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content()), to no avail. wpautop(get_the_content()) was the closest thing to styled I could get. I am retrieving the post using the_post() for now, could that be the issue, and if so, which is the best way to retrieve a post?**

**I have tried retrieving the post in various ways and it's still unstyled, so I decided to inspect the elements in the browser and found that WordPress is indeed attaching a class to the elements but just where on earth is that class? I read somewhere about a css reset being the possible cause -- how does one bypass any css reset issues?**

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was just a header issue. Solved by adding:

```
<head>
    <?php do_action('wp_head'); ?>
</head>
```